# How can I use mypy's typechecking to enforce the signature of a callable type

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that takes another function x as its argument. Function x can have 2 different types of signatures and I would like to enforce this through type hinting:

```
TYPE_A = Callable[[int, int], int]
TYPE_B = Callable[[int], int]

def my_func(x: Union[TYPE_A, TYPE_B]) -> None:
    ...determine x is of which type and use x accordingly...
```

I am running into 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to check whether x is of `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B`. I tried using `isinstance(x, TYPE_A)` and it generates a type error.
2. If I am using another way to determine the type of x, for instance, using `signature` to determine the signature of x inside `my_func` (if x has 1 parameter or 2 parameters), `mypy` still thinks there is a type error whenever I run x:

   ```
   from inspect import signature
   def my_func(x: Union[TYPE_A, TYPE_B]):
       sig = signature(x)
       if len(sig.parameters.values()) == 1:
            x(1)  // mypy thinks this is a type error: too few args
       else:
            x(1, 2) // mypy thinks this is type error: too many args
   ```

Is there a way for me to write a function that takes another function as its input, and use type checking to enforce that the input function has the correct signature?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does seem like there is currently no way for mypy to infer the correct type for `x`, so I think the best that you can do is to use `typing.cast` to force `x` to the desired type:

```
from typing import *

from inspect import signature

TYPE_A = Callable[[int, int], int]
TYPE_B = Callable[[int], int]


def my_func(x: Union[TYPE_A, TYPE_B]):
    sig = signature(x)
    if len(sig.parameters.values()) == 1:
        x = cast(TYPE_B, x)
        x(1)
    else:
        x = cast(TYPE_A, x)
        x(1, 2)
```